# Gestures in Stack blocked

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app where I intend to show pinned offers on a map. On to of this map, will be a scrollable view that will show the offers in "text" form (basically a list of the offers which are pinned on the map).

I also want the scrollview to just cover about half the screen at start, but it can then be scrolled up to cover the whole map view. This is why I have the padding.

Everything works as intended, but my ScrollView is blocking me from moving and zooming the map?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: globals.themeColor4,
          title: Text('MY APP'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: _mapInitialized
                  ? _map
                  : Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Loading.."),
                      ),
                    ),
            ),

            SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 300, 0, 0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(children: _offers),
            ),)
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Any ideas?

Image 1: Results of suggested solution below:

[image: NOT what I want]

Image 2: This is what I want, where the view slides up and hides the map:

[image: What I want]

Comment: Don't use padding, try to use Container in an Align widget and specify the height. Make Scrollview child of the container. I did not understand completely your question but give it a try if it solves your issue. Or we can discuss more if still not solved

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh could you provide a sample of how you mean? I added screenshots now as well.

Comment: Referring to the first image, you want youScrollview to scroll and the above where the map is displaying, you want to use map also, Right?

Comment: Do you want the Map to remain exactly as it is when you scroll down (eg. the ScrollView stacks on top of it), or do you want the Map to be pushed upwards as if it's part of the ScrollView?

Comment: @Ovidiumap should remain in place. Just the view should scroll up to cover it.

Comment: If that's the case, when you scroll down, the layout needs to dynamically change so that the top of the ScrollView is actually moved upwards until it reaches the top of the screen (so the ScrollView doesn't actually scroll but the visual effect is the same), and it only starts scrolling once it reaches the top of the screen. This way, when the Map is visible, there is nothing stacked on top of it and gestures will not be blocked. You need some sort of listener on the ScrollView (or maybe a CustomScrollView using Slivers) to achieve that. It's not going to be easy but it can definitely be done.

Comment: @Ovidiu yes Slivers is way to go, also you can do this by manually handling the gestures, with `dy` values of gestures, you can animate the bottombar. With pictures it's much more clear now :) Now I'm deleting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to actually have the Map on top of the Stack so that it always reacts to gestures, and to change the layout when the ScrollView is scrolled so that visually the ScrollView goes on top of the Map. Try out the code below:

Initialize a `ScrollController` in the state of the widget:

```
final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Add a listener to the `scrollController` in `initState`:

```
scrollController.addListener(() {
  setState(() {}); // triggers rebuild with the new Container height
});
```

And then `build`:

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    SingleChildScrollView( // this is your list
      controller: scrollController,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
      child: Column(
        children: List.generate(50, (int index) => Container( // your list items
          height: 50,
          color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.orange : Colors.green,
        )),
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("TAPPED");
      },
      child: Container(
        height: max(0, 300.0 - (scrollController.hasClients ? scrollController.offset : 0)),
        child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 300, // fixed height for the Map
              child: Column( // this is where your Map would be
                children: List.generate(6, (int index) => Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.purple,
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

The `Container` shrinks from its initial height to 0 as you scroll the `ScrollView`, which is visually the same as the `ScrollView` scrolling on top of the Map. the `max` function of the `math` package is used to prevent the `Container` from having a height below 0.

The `Wrap` widget prevents its child from overflowing despite having a fixed height of 300 and a parent `Container` that might have a height of less than 300.

(Yes I know I initially suggested a CustomScrollView with Slivers but this approach actually seemed a lot easier and quicker - that being said I am not sure of the performance implications of calling `setState` every time the `ScrollView` is scrolled - testing on lower end devices might be required)